# Can I assume that steam leaking from a rigid insulated tank is an isentropic process?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, reversibility

I’m trying to solve this problem. If you have a rigid insulated tank with $V=10\ {\rm m}^3$ which is initially filled with steam at $p_1=0.7\ {\rm MPa}$ and $T_1=240\ {\rm C}^\circ$. The tank develops a leak and steam slowly escapes until the pressure is $0.15MPa$. I need to then find the final temperature of the water and the amount of mass which exited the tank. From what I understand from my book I can assume it is internally reversible and since it’s insulated it’s adiabatic so therefore it is isentropic. Is this correct? And if so can somebody explain why? Steam leaving a tank seems really irreversible to me, but I can’t think of another way to solve the problem without assuming this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The steam that remains in the tank at any point in time has been doing work on the steam ahead of it to force it slowly out of the tank (just as if the steam ahead of it were a piston).  This slow expansion of the remaining steam is essentially quasi static, and with no heat transfer.  So it is basically an internally reversible process.  You can also. analyze this situation using the open system (control volume) version of the first law of thermodynamics.  Of course, in passing through the hole, the exiting steam undergoes an additional isenthalpic change.

ADDENDUM

Here is the open system analysis.  Let U be the internal energy of the steam in the tank during the seepage, m be the mass of steam in the tank, let u(=U/m) be the internal energy per unit mass of the steam in the tank, and let h be the enthalpy per unit mass of the steam, both in the tank and exiting the tank.  Then from the open system version of the first law, $$dU=d(mu)=hdm$$or, equivalently,
$$mdu+udm=(u+Pv)dm$$where v is the specific volume of the steam in the tank.  From the previous equation, it follows that $$mdu=Pvdm$$.  If we now substitute du=Tds-Pdv, we obtain:  $$mTds=P(mdv+vdm)$$where v is the entropy per unit mass of the steam.  But the volume of the tank V=mv is constant.  So the right hand side is zero, and it follows that $$ds=0$$

Comment: Thank you so much! That makes sense. I considered using the open system version of the first law to analyze the situation but I couldn’t figure out how to apply it. I know Q, W and mass flowing in are all zero but I couldn’t figure out where to go from there. I don’t have a lot of information and I didn’t know what assumptions I could make.

Comment: I’ll add a little about the derivation using the 1st law when I get home later.

Comment: Thank you! I would appreciate that. I’ve really been struggling with this question. You’ve been a great help.

Comment: See the ADDENDUM

Comment: Oh thank you! You explained that really well. I appreciate your help.